# Reset camera position/rotation when using TrackballControls

Tags: javascript, jquery, webgl, three.js

I have a webgl application with threejs. It uses TrackballControls to control the camera. I have a button which I want to use to reset the scene, so, the camera should go to the initial state. I currently have this (jquery):

```
$('#reset').click(function() {
    camera.position.set(0, 0 , 400);
    camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
});
```

But strangely, when I log the position and rotation, they are not as they should be and the camera is not at the correct place. What am I doing wrong, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Until the bug is fixed (see comment on Yuval Adam's answer), a working (though dirty) solution is to remove the camera from the scene, then to create a new one, add controls to it and add the new camera to the scene.</s>

**Update:**
TrackballControls now has a `reset()` method. Call this after the tween completes and all is well! (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/4f800f61809560c434bbbf12e76c3931e8e8c0fb)

Answer (score 1):

The `camera.position` should always be up-to-date, make sure you're looking at the right `camera` and that it's not out of scope. Ideally, it should be a global var on the window.

Regarding the `camera.rotation`, you should check if your camera has:

```
camera.useQuaternion == true
```

Some controls set this on the camera as a prerequisite. If this is the case, the camera angle is set by the `camera.quaternion` and not by the `camera.rotation`. Granted, `TrackballControls` do not have this behavior (as of r49, at least).

---

**Edit:** As it seems from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/821 there is indeed a bug with manually adjusting the `camera` that messes up the `TrackballControls`.

Comment: There is only one camera in the scene and it has a global scope within the script trough the "camera" variable, so it should work? Still, it does not.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. I tested this on http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_camera_trackball.html and there's definitely a bug. Check out https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/821, it might be worth another look.

Comment: The buttons don't really work for me either (w,a,s,d). Something happens, but it is very schocky and unclear what really happens.

Comment: The `TrackballControls` work just fine until you mess with the `camera.rotation`. *That* is the bug, not anything else.

Comment: ok, but even if I dont set rotation, it still won't reset correctly

Comment: True, this is also relevant for setting `camera.position` as well.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this until the bug is fixed?

Comment: An slightly-ugly hack I can think of would be to create new `controls` after resetting your camera. That should do the trick.

Comment: New controls don't do the trick unfortunately. The behaviour is different, but not really better, still the camera is oriented wrong after the "reset".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the camera.rotation to (0,0,0) change the camera.up to (0,1,0). You can use Tween as well to animate it.